# Run JS code after user signed in with Devise in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to run some javascript code after user is logged in.

I'm using this code to redirect a user to his profile.

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path
    //call js code
  end
```

It's possible to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you pass simple html request or js request for login ?

Comment: maybe you can change your solution: after login, devise will navigate to the particular page, in this html page, add your javascripts.

Comment: @LipingHuang I thought in that approach, but that will display the javascript every time when the user enter in that particular page.

Comment: @exsnake you can using the helper to check is the user login correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code to run some js code after signin:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:js_code] = true
    profile_path
end
```

## In profile view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    <% if session.has_key?(:js_code) %>
      session.delete(:js_code)
     // write your js code here
    <% end%>

  })
</script>
```

Comment: I get no parameters `Started GET "/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-19 03:12:42 -0400`

Comment: didn't work. I tried the code in another method and worked. It's must be the `after_sign_in_path_for` method.